# How can I modify this Postgres function to work with Array of JSON objects?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following postgres function that converts all the keys within the JSON object to camel case format.

```
CREATE FUNCTION underscore_to_camel_case(s text)
RETURNS json
IMMUTABLE
LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
    SELECT to_json(substring(s, 1, 1) || substring(replace(initcap(replace(s, '_', ' ')), ' ', ''), 2));
$$;

CREATE FUNCTION json_underscore_to_camel_case(data json)
RETURNS json
IMMUTABLE
LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
    SELECT ('{'||string_agg(underscore_to_camel_case(key)||':'||value, ',')||'}')::json
    FROM json_each(data)
$$;
```

Example:

```
select json_underscore_to_camel_case('{"first_key": "value1", "second_key":"value2"}');
```

gets converted to:

```
{"firstKey":"value1","secondKey":"value2"}
```

But it doesn't work for array of objects. How can I modify it for it to be able to work with an JSON Array?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: Passing ```[{"first_key": "value1", "second_key":"value2"}, {"firstKey":"value1","secondKey":"value2"}]``` throws cannot deconstruct an array as an object error.